# Firebase dynamic link: deeplink always empty

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, ionic3, xcode9, firebase-dynamic-links

I am developing an app in ionic 3 for android and ios platform. For deeplinking, I am using cordova firebase dynamic link plugin.

This is working fine for android platform. But in the ios platform, though it is not throwing any error, it is not working.

My current ionic code.

```
this.platform.ready()
.then(() => {
  return this.firebaseDynamicLinks.onDynamicLink();
}).then((dynamicLink:any) => {
  console.log(dynamicLink); // always gives  {matchType: "weak", deepLink:""} in ios
}).catch((error: any) => {
  console.log(error);
});
```

The android part working fine. But in ios, the deeplink is always coming as empty.

my manually created dynamic url

https://xxxx.app.goo.gl/?link=`<encoded url to mysite>`&apn=`<android bundle id>`&ibi=`<ios bundle id>`

The provided link is returning HTTP 200 status when opening in the browser.

Testing steps (in ios):

In my iphone (ios9) I have placed this dynamic link in notepad
Then by clicking on the dynamic link the app opens.
In the console, I get

{matchType: "weak", deepLink:""}

Comment: That looks as expected. You're not putting a deeplink in the dynamic link (the link parameter is empty).

Comment: Sorry @IanBarber , I had done a mistake during writing the question. I have updated the question. Actually I am passing the encoded url in link param. But it is working in android, not in ios.

Comment: Yeah, actually looking at that again weak match seems odd here, as its coming through to your app. Does a generated link from the console work (particularly a short one)

Comment: no, the short url also does not work.

Comment: Ah, that's a sign of something not set up right then. Since the app is opening I am guessing that universal links are firing OK, so the issue likely exists within the cordova plugin - what I would do is step through that in the debugger, and compare to the iOS quickstart: https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-ios/blob/master/dynamiclinks/DynamicLinksExample/AppDelegate.m